# SQL Server Instances

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 db that is on the MSSQLSERVER instance.  I want another user who only has SQL Server 2008 express installed to be able to use an app that accesses that database.

How do I install the db on SQL Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the user be accessing the same database?  If so, you will need to ensure that the application can connect to the default instance on your pre-existing installation.

If you are talking about the same database schema, but just on a different location then you can just backup the database on the MSSQLSERVER instance and restore it on the SQL Express instance.  SQL Express is a named instance so the connection string in the application will need to reflect something like `.\SQLEXPRESS`.

Also, versions will need to be considered.  The SQL Express instance should be 2008 or 2008 R2 to not have compatibility issues.